# Truncate TextView based on String length

Tags: android, textview, truncate, android-relativelayout, ellipsize

I am trying to achieve a layout where two TextViews ie. tv_username and tv_date are to be aligned side by side. If the username is short the username and date should show completely and if the name is long, the username should truncate at the end and the date should show completely. Something like so :-

[image]

In any case both the TextViews shold have a max of 5dp spacing between them i.e the date should always be at the right of username with a margin of 5dp and not aligned to right in the parent. I have tried the below code, but it pushes the date Textview out of the screen with a longer username :-

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/value_3"
            android:padding="@dimen/value_5"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/value_10"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/value_10"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/value_5">

                 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="@integer/value_1"
               android:text="Samantha George Jefferson and some more text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_fourteen"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/friendly_date"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack_a38"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_twelv"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I used `ConstraintLayout` but the result is the same.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="@integer/value_1"
                android:text="Johnvfvjdfjgdkjhgjdgdjkghdjkghkjdhgdhgdgjkhjdfg"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_fourteen"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/friendly_date"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack_a38"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_username"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_twelv"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I think Linear-layout with it's weight property will solve your issue. You can set weight as per your requirement as 4:2 or 3:1 or may be 3:2 ? Otherwise, try it with Constraint layout.

Comment: @JaiminModi can you give me an example of Constraint layout in this context? With Linearlayout weight wouldn't it still keep space between the textviews if there is a fixed weight?

Comment: With Constraint layout you can specify space between those two view in layout by specifying minimum two constraints vertically and horizontally. For more detail you can go through Google developer console.

Comment: or you can simply limit tv_username size by setting android:maxEms="10" (ex)

Comment: @renzvader maxEms did not work in this case

Comment: @JaiminModi It would be easier for me to understand +if you could provide me an example in the context of my question.

Comment: *date should always be at the left of username* ? .. on your images date is on the right of the username

Comment: @Selvin Rectified the question

Comment: @JaiminModi please check my update

Comment: @ Check answer pls. and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a TableLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="0">

    <TableRow>
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="1 hour ago"
            android:textColor="#5000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

TableLayout can do what you want, as stated by @m4n3k4s, but if you want to do it with a ConstraintLayout, then just add this to your TextView in the xml layout

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:maxWidth="160dp"
```

Obviously set maxWidth to your desired value.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is add following line to your `tv_username` TextView
which are

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
android:toLeftOf="+@id/tv_date"
android:toStartOf="+@id/tv_date"
android:ellipsize="end|right"
```

The way it will work is once your `tv_date` is drawn at the end `tv_username` will be drawn and it will be truncated if it needs more space than available

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't singleLine deprecated?

Comment: ***date should ... not aligned to right in the parent***